# Keras model.predict() faster when called with the same image again

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I know that Keras model.predict() is slower the very first time it is called.
The reason for this is explained here:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8724

However, let’s say that I feed model.predict() a number of images and print the prediction times in a loop. If I duplicate this loop, all those times will be shorter the second time. If the time is about one second for each image the first time, the time drops about 40-50% the second time. Why is this?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the difference between the situation you describe and the one in the github issue you pointed to. Could you elaborate a bit please ?

Comment: I will try to be clearer: 
The github issue discusses the one very first call to model.predict(), no matter whether subsequent calls are made with the same or with other images. This first call will always take much longer time than subsequent calls. In addition, there can be a difference between the subsequent calls as well. If you call predict on an image you have called predict on before, the prediction will be almost twice as fast.